# How to open a java file with java editor that eclipse owns?

Tags: eclipse, editor, rcp

I build a RCP application.And I want to use the java editor to open the java file.So how could I connect to  the java editor when I double click the java file,the RCP application will open the file with the java editor that the eclipse owns?

Comment: I'm not sure that is possible. That eclipse editor is built into Eclipse. You can either open the file with Eclipse in which case you will use the editor or you can just use something else. (Notepad++)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on Windows, simply:

1) Open Windows file manager

2) Select Tools, Folder Options

3) Configure .java files to open with Eclipse

These links provide additional details, if needed:

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/OpenFileFeature
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307859

Comment: No,I just want to embed the eclipse java editor into my rcp application.